# domxml_open_mem - Getting error while calling domxml_open_mem() function

Tags: php, xml, dom

When i am calling domxml_open_mem() function in my project, i am getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_open_mem()" error. Then i have tested that domxml_open_mem() function is exists not or not, then i understood that this function is not exists in server, I am using PHP 5.2.9 version, and the server is Linux. In phpInfo() the following is the status for dom

```
DOM/XML                  enabled
DOM/XML API Version      20031129
libxml Version           2.7.8
HTML Support             enabled
XPath Support            enabled
XPointer Support         enabled
Schema Support           enabled
RelaxNG Support          enabled
```

Need i install any .so file like domxml.so, How can i install this file or How can i enable this in server?

Please anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 3):

`domxml_open_mem()` is a PHP4-legacy function. You shouldn't be using it. It is part of the PHP4 DOMXML extension, which wasn't included when PHP was upgraded to v5.

PHP5 introduced a number of alternative XML processing libraries that you can use instead.

See here for a list of them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

If you absolutely can't live without the old `domxml_open_mem()` function, then there is a wrapper library that someone has written that basically takes all the old functions and classes that were deprecated, and re-implements them using the PHP5 equivalents.

See here: http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/domxml-php4-php5/

If you have old PHP4 code that you want to get up-and-running with a minimum of fuss, then this is maybe possibly a way to do it.

In most cases, however, you would be far better off simply re-writing your code to use the newer PHP5 XML libraries.